# Returning an success indicator with information

Tags: c#, .net, exception, return-value

I am currently building an API that does a certain action that should indicate if that action was successful or not. I also need to know why the action fails if it fails.
How should I implement this? Should I use a void return type and throw an exception when something wrong happens or should I return a bool along with some kind of message to indicate why it failed?

Comment: Is something going wrong an exceptional case that will rarely happen, or is having a problem an expected standard use case?  Whether or not the problem is exceptional should give you some idea as to whether or not it should throw an exception.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine how often this would happen, and if the answer is often, consider using a string by reference parameter to get the message and the method with a boolean return value.

Alternatively just have a string return value that returns string.Empty if it succeeds, and just check the length of it to know if it succeeded or failed.

Third option is to return an enum as another answerer said, that would indicate its reason, but not be able to hold any information from another exception etc.

If it happens rarely, throw an exception.

Comment: And if you do end up using a string return value with string.Empty as the success value, I suggest commenting it in your code since it isn't a great practice to use strings as indicators.

Answer (score 1):

Void and exception should be fine in my opinion.

If it failed, the exception message should be enough to tell you what happened.

If it succeeded, then go on your merry way.

Comment: Beaten to the punch. Additionally with this method you can throw specific types of exceptions, so you can handle them differently in each case.

Answer (score 1):

If a method will generally be called *directly* by code which is expecting a particular failure scenario and can deal with it, then the method should distinguish between success or the expected failure scenarios by some means other than throwing exceptions.  Note that failure scenarios which the caller is *not* expecting should throw exceptions in any case.  If some calling code will be not expecting a particular failure scenario but other code will, it may be helpful to have two versions of a method--one of which throws an exception in the problem scenario and one of which returns some other kind of error indication.

A common pattern used in Microsoft's libraries is to have a pair of methods, using the naming pattern `DoSomething` and `TryDoSomething`.  The `DoSomething` method will throw an exception if it fails.  Any data it should give to the caller will be indicated in the return value.  The second method will return a `bool` value indicating whether the operation succeeded; any data for the caller will be indicated via `out` parameter.  This approach may have been reasonable when Microsoft started using it, but it does not interact well with language features which have been added since then.  Among other things:

- Interfaces like `IEnumerable<T>` which use a type parameter only for function return values are allowed to be covariant with respect to that type (allowing code which expects e.g. an `IEnumerable<Animal>` to accept an `IEnumerable<Cat>`).  Covariance does not work, however, with `out` parameters.  If the pattern had been e.g. `T TryGetSomething(ref bool Success)` instead of `bool TryGetSomething(ref T Result)`, covariance would have been usable with "try" methods.
- Both VB.NET and C# allow statements which both declare and assign a variable to infer the type based upon the assignment expression.  Although this works nicely with methods whose return value supplies data, it does not work with methods that give data to the caller via `out` parameter.

In addition to those limitations, the Microsoft pattern may be less than ideal for your scenario because it includes no mechanism for a function which fails to indicate why it did so.  Additionally, while Microsoft recommends against having one method which can act as either `DoSomething` and `TryDoSomething` based upon a passed-in parameter, using one method for both has a major advantage: if an operation requires multiple sub-operations which might succeed or fail, and if failure of any piece means failure of the operation as a whole, one might want to have a failure within an inner method throw an exception if called from `DoSomething`, but return an error code if called from `TryDoSomething`.  Using separate "throw" or "don't throw" variants of the inner methods requires having duplicating the code which calls them--icky.

I would thus suggest that you might want to define an `INotifyOfFailure` interface and have your methods take an optional `INotifyOfFailure` parameter (default null).  If a failure occurs and the `INotifyOfFailure` parameter is non-null, call a method on it to inform it of the failure; it can store information about the failure internally; after the function returns, it can ask the object it passed in whether the operation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` with a message is probably best. Ultimately Exceptions are expensive - both for your API to handle and the client to handle - so it is best to avoid them entirely and use a construct such as the aforementioned `bool` and `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions should be thrown if an exception happened, i.e. something that wasn't expected.

Another option is to use an `enum` so you can return different results. Something like

```
public enum Results
{
    Error,
    Warning,
    Minor,
}
```

Then they can use it

```
var result = YourApiCall();
if (result == Result.Error)
    // Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class that derives from `EventArgs`, and add a `Boolean` property to check for an error, then if true have a `String` property they can get the error message from.